# DataGridView generate IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

DataGridView gives me IndexOutOfRangeException while firing CellClick exception. Before it i tried to update dataSource like the following way:

```
dataGridView2.DataSource = null;
dataGridView2.DataSource = _securititesToAdd;

StackTrace:    at System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.get_Current()
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.DataGridViewDataConnection.OnRowEnter(DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnRowEnter(DataGridViewCell& dataGridViewCell, Int32 columnIndex, Int32 rowIndex, Boolean canCreateNewRow, Boolean validationFailureOccurred)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.SetCurrentCellAddressCore(Int32 columnIndex, Int32 rowIndex, Boolean setAnchorCellAddress, Boolean validateCurrentCell, Boolean throughMouseClick)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnCellMouseDown(HitTestInfo hti, Boolean isShiftDown, Boolean isControlDown)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnCellMouseDown(DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseDown(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   at PortfolioInvestment.Program.Main() in D:\MyProjects\PortfolioInvestment\PortfolioInvestment\Program.cs:line 23
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve], including a `StackTrace` of the exception when it fires.

Comment: @mjwills attached a stack trace. It's quite hard to attach all code. But i try to add new object to list that is DataSource for dataGridView, once i try to file Cell Click Event it gives me OutOfRange

Comment: Then what do you do in the Cell Click Event? This is where the exception is raised and there you have the problem. Show that code.

Comment: @Steve It's just an empty snippet for this event

Comment: @Steve it's event not achieved my debug point at start of the method

Comment: The stacks suggest your code entered the CellMouseDown event

Comment: In most cell events, you need to check `e.RowIndex >= 0` and  `e.ColumnIndex >=0` and `e.RowIndex < dataGridView.NewRowIndex`. It depends to the requirements.

Comment: An empty event doesn't throw an exception. Show the line that throws!

Comment: Application.Run(new Form1(unitOfWork));

Comment: That often comes up after having removed an expected element. Is the DataSource filled and showing before you click? Where is the DataSource code you show sitting???

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the datasource during cell click event since the event and surrounding handling of that event depends on the current data of the grid.

You have some original data in the grid. You click into the cell and datagrid view collects context of your click (like index of current row) and fires the event. If you remove the datasource now then the current row index becomes invalid. And the rest of DataGridView internal logic will fail because of this.

You need to change your logic to add rows to existing datasource or handle the event independently on another eventloop cycle using `BeginInvoke` for example.

Comment: __If__ that is what he actually does, this is a good explanation!